# Loop Multiple Values In Variable Output To csv Powershell

Tags: powershell

I created a script where a dialogue box pops up and the value you enter goes into foreach. I didn't know how to take a single value created in a running script and process it. It worked, although I knew it wasn't the right way to do it.. Now I've created a loop to prompt again and the goal is to append each value into a csv. My problem is now the original variable value is overwritten by the next value put into the prompt before writing out to a csv. How can I build each entry into the looping dialogue box and create the csv?

You can see in the powershell script that I create $x from the value input to the dialogue box, then I cycle the script into a function that repeats the dialogue prompt. When it does that it overwrites the first value of $x. I'm trying to figure out how to build many values before writing the all to the csv.

This script is to have a user enter a group, check it against Active Directory, and then generate a CSV.

...Update## I was able to resolve it. I'm removing the original test code and putting the final product. The following script creates a form which asks for an object in Active Directory. It checks active directory then outputs to a spreadsheet, and asks again until canceled. Building the variable repeatedly.

```
function ProcessOut ($x , $group) {
            $result = @()

            Foreach ($Line in $x){
                            $GroupName = "domain.local\" + $group
                            $OutList = New-Object System.Object
                            $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "DisplayPath_GroupName" -value $GroupName
                            $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "RuleName" -value "AutomaticApproval"
                            $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "RuleClauses" -value '
                            $result+= $OutList
            }

            #Output to csv
            $outputfilepath = 'c:\users\technician\desktop\'
            $outputfilename = $outputfilepath + 'FinalFile.csv'
            $result | export-csv $outputfilename  -Append -encoding unicode -NoTypeInformation
}

function PromptInput {
            add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

            $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
            $form.Text = 'Group Auto-Approval Setup'
            $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,230)
            $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

            $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(170,100)
            $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
            $OKButton.Text = 'OK'
            $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
            $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
            $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

            $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(260,100)
            $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
            $CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
            $CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

            $form.CancelButton = $CancelButton    
            $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)      

            $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
            $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)
            $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
            $label.Text = "Enter a group name:"
            $form.Controls.Add($label)

            $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
            $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,65)
            $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,120)
            $form.Controls.Add($textBox)

            $form.Topmost = $true

            $form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
            $result = $form.ShowDialog()

            if ($result -eq 'Cancel'){
                            Exit
            }

            if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){
                            $x = $textBox.Text
            }

            return $x
}

$continue = $true
while($continue){
            $input = PromptInput
            Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.visualbasic

            $searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(SAMAccountName=$input)"
            $result = $searcher.FindOne()

            if($result){
                            ProcessOut $result $input
                            $additional = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to enter another group?" , "Status" , 4)
                            if ($additional -eq "NO"){
                                            Exit
                            }
            } else{
                            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Group name not found - Please enter a valid group name")
            }
}
```

Comment: Place `$result = @()` before the function definition. It would also be much more pwsh-ish to have $x be an array of group name strings. The code could be `Get-GroupList -Groups xxx,yyy,zzz`.

Comment: an array before the function makes sense but it isn't working out in the script. i think get-grouplist won't work be i am adding them one by one in a prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList or an Array to build things up. Create this at the Global level so that it is accessible within the code. Example:

```
# Create an empty array outside of the loop
$myArray = @()

# Get all running processes
$processes = Get-Process

# for each process in the list of processes we are going to do something
foreach($process in $processes)
{
    # Create a Pipe separated string
    $myString = $process.Name + "|" + $process.Id

    # Add the process name to my array.
    $myArray += $myString
}

# Export the array to a CSV file
$myArray | Export-Csv -Path c:\myfile.csv
```

Or if you don't like arrays (I don't for many reasons...) Try a List...

Replace the 2nd line with:

```
$myArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Replacing the 14th line with

```
$myArray.Add($myString) > $null
```

Notice that I am piping the output to null. This is to stop it echoing back which may / maynot be useful to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working out.  but i'm trying to approach it with it.  this is tricky.

Comment: Hmm. I am also encountering this sporadically. What version of PoSh are you running?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by using 'while' and passing it to a functionl